# Carrying Form data from one form to another form? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a small affiliate network and one of my offers, I have a form for it where I am collecting page viewer data for my own records, I then want to post that data to ANOTHER form automatically so the people do not need to complete the same information twice.

How would I do this?

I googled for nearly an hour and couldn't find anything.

The page can be viewed here

http://getthiscrazyoffer.com/jobs/index.php

Comment: How many users do you have on this system?  If it is something used by a small number, a GreaseMonkey extension could help you here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two good ways to do this:

Way one: switch your page to using AJAX. You can make two AJAX requests: one to each PHP file.

Way two: You can use the `cURL` plugin for PHP to make GET and POST requests automatically from the server; thus you can send the data to the PHP file for the other form. In particular, for POST requests, you'll need to:

1. Use `$curl = curl_init(url)` to generate a request
2. use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true)` to make it a POST request
3. use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)`, where `$data` contains the form field values which the other form can retrieve via `$_POST`
4. Use `curl_exec` to run the request.

Comment: the thing is, i dont "control" the other form, one form belongs to me - the other to another company, is that going to be an issue?

Comment: It might be an issue if you use "way one" as listed in my answer, since cross-domain AJAX (generally) isn't possible. But "way two" should work, as long as you can find out the names of the relevant form fields so that you can set `$data` correctly.

Comment: $data needs to be an array, whose keys are the names of form fields (generally, the contents of the `name` attributes of `input` tags), and whose values are the contents of those fields. For instance, if the second form contains `<input type="text" name="User">`, $data should look like `array('User' => $userName)`, where $userName is the value that should go in the User field of the second form.

Comment: If the second form is using `GET` to send its form data, you may be able to do this with just `file_get_contents`, as in `file_get_contents('http://othersite.com/form.php?User=username')`, but for `POST` you'll need to use cURL.

Comment: yeah its post but so far i think i know what to do, doesnt seem overly hard. just its really late here already so im gonna sleep on it but once i get this live man, i honor my committments so keep abreast of changes on this post

Comment: No payment is necessary or expected :)

Comment: people keep telling me that this is IMPOSSIBLE... :/ Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your need, the easier way to carry data to another page is through cookies.  If you are using jQuery, you may look at this page to see how cookies work:

[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/ that may actually work BUT i do not own form 2, only form 1... will that work?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in your original question that form 2 is outside of your control.  You will need to know what the form 2 accepts as input, which could be HTTP GET, HTTP POST.   Cookie is unlikely to work across servers.